# Check if key exists in smarty array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    'name1' => array('city1', 'city2', 'city3'),
    'name2' => array('city1', 'city4'),
    'namen' => array('city1', 'city7', 'cityn')
);
```

Which is passed to smarty as : `$my_names`
There is a loop in my Smarty template that looks like this:

```
{{foreach from=$names item=name}}
  {{foreach from=$cities item=city}}
  //Check if name1 exist and after check if the city is in the array for that name
  {{/foreach}}
{{/foreach}}
```

I fail to see how would I use the `$name` and `$city` to access the array `$my_names`

I have tried doing `if($my_names.$name.$city)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: unable to understand. you have passed array in $my_names and using $names in smarty. Moreover, whats $cities?

Comment: Did You try `{{if $my_names.$name.$city neq NULL}} do stuff here {{/if}}` ?

Answer (score 21):

This notation will work too :

```
{if 'needle'|array_key_exists:$haystack}
....
{/if}
```

Comment: This feature deprecated in 2023

Answer (score 14):

You can use the **array_key_exists()** function to check whether the key is in the array.

```
{if array_key_exists('needle', $haystack)} 
    DoSomethingAboutIt 
{/if}
```